# Azure Could not find cloud source (Apache Tomcat)

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, azure, web-applications

I am getting the error: 
The cloud source of component( https://azuredownloads.blob.core.windows.net/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.23.zip) is not available, so it cannot be deployed

while publishing the my app on azure. Help!

And is it a prerequisite to have tomcat before I do that?
My settings under Server Configuration are set to deploy a 3rd party server on Azure

Comment: Well, I just clicked that blob link - it doesn't exist. Have you tried downloading tomcat yourself, zipping it up, and placing it into one of your own blobs?

Answer (score 0):

May I know where you got the link: https://azuredownloads.blob.core.windows.net/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.23.zip? Per my understanding, zip file: https://azuredownloads.blob.core.windows.net/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.20.zip works fine. The sample screenshot displayed in the document's Server Configuration section on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh690945.aspx#server_configuration_properties uses Tomcat 8.0.20 as well. Please try it and see if it works on your side.
[image]

Comment: I did try it with the tomcat 8.0.20 also. It still gives the same error.

Comment: Do you mean you could not access the URL: https://azuredownloads.blob.core.windows.net/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.20.zip? It seems the issue could not be reproduced on my side, please refer to Server Configuration section on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh690945.aspx#server_configuration_properties and let us know which step is blocked (as you mentioned: gives the same error)